How to test and control this gauge pointer? (multimeter movement?)

This is from an old honda motorcycle fuel gauge (its a knockoff, not OEM). It looks similar to analog multimeter movement. I'd like help on how to wire so I can control the position with an esp32 or arduino, or at least test if the movement is working. (I dont have the electric diagram nor the motorycle itself just this gauge)
I labeled A,B,C to simplify instructions. thank you.
Edit: Thanks for the replies, I was able to get movement by applying voltage in series with a small resistor across the A and B terminals. Connecting the C terminal to the negative(ground) of the power source diminishes the rate of movement significantly.
I got the most movement when close to 12v with a 22ohm resistor (around 90 degrees of movement which is the maximum movement on the frame that has a slightly higher zero), but the small resistor ran a little hot, so I still need to adjust the values to scale down things to 5 or 3.3v and will test PWM control after.

There’s not much to go on here except that the two resistors are 150 and 100 ohms respectively.  Since it’s just a pointer and doesn’t do a significant amount of work, it won’t need a large current to operate, but applying 12V directly to it may be more than it can tolerate.  I’d suggest getting hold of a few resistors of 100 ohms to 1k and see how it behaves with 3.3V (or whatever you’re supplying your ESP32 with) supplied via a resistance to limit current so you can explore the device’s behaviour without fear of damaging it

You may find that it’s effectively a voltmeter, reading 0 to 12, so you may need to change the resistors to lower value ones to get full scale from a lower voltage.  You can get the ESP32 to output a PWM signal to set the needle position, depending on the current drawn by the device you may need a buffer (such as a transistor).

Talko, Just going off-the-cuff from memory, A is wired to body/ground, C is wired to +12 V through a fuse, and B is from the fuel sending unit. The resistor values I see there are in the right magnitude, too. But I can't just look at a picture of one, without any measurements or tests, and tell you that my recollection applies here.

use a 1.5 V alkaline cell ... see if you get any response from the pointer

This is called an "air core" meter movement. The X and Y coils (there is 90° between them) are driven by quadrature currents (proportional to \$\sin{\theta}\$ and \$\cos{\theta}\$) in order to drive the needle to angle \$\theta\$. The ratio of the two currents is the important factor provided the currents are in approximately the correct range. To drive it over a wide angle you need bipolar drive on both coils to hit all 4 quadrants.  Image from here

Typically this is accomplished with a special driver chip. Here is one:

This provides the ability to make a wide angle meter movement (it could actually cover 360°) without the huge magnet assembly that would be required for a reasonably linear 240° or 270° D'Arsonval meter movement. One disadvantage is that it doesn't inherently return to zero (though a hairspring can be added).

@GodJihyo The circuit above also uses DC currents, there is no AC involved. Maybe you've described a simplified way of driving an air core coil for applications where the needle angle is confined to less than one quadrant. OP is using an Arduino to generate the currents so they could go either way depending on what they want to accomplish.

These meters are not like a d'Arsonval meter movement which has a coil moving in the field of a fixed magnet, they have a magnet or piece of iron moving in the magnetic fields of two coils, a control coil and a deflection coil. The coils are attached to the vehicle's positive voltage (typically +12 V or +6 V) on one terminal, ground on another terminal, and the fuel sensor on the third terminal. The fuel sensor is a rheostat and it's resistance depends on the amount of fuel in the tank. The position of the rheostat changes the balance of the magnetic fields of the coils by deflecting more or less current, when more current goes through the control coil the needle moves towards Empty, when more current goes through the deflect coil the needle moves towards Full.
You can see in the photo that there are two coils, wound at right angles to each other. This is called a cross-coil gauge. The resistors are probably to calibrate it or adjust the linearity of the movement.
To use it you could possibly connect the voltage as it would be in a vehicle and control the current through the sensor connection with a transistor.
Here's a diagram of how it is connected

from this site which also has an explanation of how it works, pretty much the same as what I already said.

A quadrature-driven movement can be controlled like you say, but only over a rather narrow range of angles. So, the arrangement you suggest where one coil has a fixed current only allows 45 degrees of motion by driving the other coil from no current to full current.
